# Blazor Server exception when using SignalR under Domain

Tags: blazor, signalr, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-signalr

Application Blazor .Net 6. I am using SignalR for WebSocket.
When I run it in local, there is no problem, I can send and receive messages, but when I publish the application under the domain, I get an error as follows.

```
Program:

    builder.Services.AddCors();
    builder.Services.AddSignalR();
    builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
    {
        opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
        new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
    });
        
    ...
    app.UseResponseCompression();
        
    app.MapHub<ExampleHub>("/ehub");
        
        
    
Code:
    hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/ehub"),
    options =>
    {
        options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
        
    }).WithAutomaticReconnect().Build();

    await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    

Error:
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost EventId: 111 SpanId: 035e261646274bda TraceId: 409cb921befed7fb1fd2e9aebe4d3922 ParentId: 0000000000000000 RequestId: 800023fd-0001-e800-b63f-84710c7967bb RequestPath: /_blazor TransportConnectionId: 5Zoh_eXhB5h8rS8JGG4rhw Unhandled exception in circuit 'KV5FZtq0dX0PIWMTtQo5Jo-8_hp5lD6O_gm9C5pCWNs'. Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (demo.domain.com:443) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: Where are you hosting it and have you enabled web socket on it? Also, you might want to check if there are any other sites running on port 443.

Comment: 443 or 80 ports are working. I installed (Programs and Features) web socket.

Comment: It works fine locally.